# Click the select tag option. Bootstrap popover closes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bugzilla, bootstrap-popover

I don't know english. I'm sorry to exchange meaningless phrases.

Click on the Select tag option. Bootstrap popover closes.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aonyaye0/3/)

**Note:** Problem mozilla firefox browser.

```js
// Bootstrap Popover
$('body').popover({
    selector: '[data-popover]',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click hover',
    title: function() {
        return $('.select_box').html();
    },
    content: '...',
    placement: 'bottom',
    delay: {
        show: 50,
        hide: 400
    }
});
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-primary' data-popover="true">hover here</button>


<div class="select_box hidden">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>Day</option>
        <option>Week</option>
        <option>Month</option>
        <option>...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You look funny speaking english

Comment: @AliMehdi Google Translate. I'm talking to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` elements have inconsistent behavior across browser, and the related events can be triggered in different moments.

Mantaining the jQuery one way you can check if the current target triggering the mouse leave is a select and if so rebind the `mouseleave` handler.

Code:

```
if (obj.currentTarget) {
    container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover')
    timeout = self.timeout;
    container.one('mouseenter', function () {
        //We entered the actual popover – call off the dogs
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        var bindLeave = function () {
            container.one('mouseleave', function (e) {
                if ($(e.target).is('select')) {
                    bindLeave();
                    return;
                }
                $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
            });
        }

        bindLeave();
    })
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/tskf0eoL/

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. Thank you very very very much. :)